# How to efficiently partition a large amount of data?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

I wonder what would be a more efficient way to partition Parquet data when storing it in S3.
In my cluster I currently have a folder `data` with a huge amount of Parquet files. I would like to change the way I save data in order to simplify the data retrieval.
I have two options. One option is to store Parquet files in the following folder path:

```
PARTITION_YEAR=2017/PARTITION_MONTH=07/PARTITION_DAY=12/my-parquet-files-go-here
```

or

```
PARTITION_DATE=20170712/my-parquet-files-go-here
```

Which of these two alternatives would be more recommended if I need to read a range of 7 days in Spark using `spark.read.parquet`?
Which alternative would be faster?

Comment: The first option is good as per me. More the partitions, more will be the number of folders. Second option will create folder for every single day in the same folder. So you will have almost 365 directories in your folder just for 1 year of data. Whereas in case of first option, your data will be well partitioned and segregated.

Comment: @ShrinivasDeshmukh: Do you refer to `PARTITION_DATE=20170712/my-parquet-files-go-here` as the first option? It will create less folders. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: nope, {PARTITION_YEAR=2017/PARTITION_MONTH=07/...} I referred to this option

Comment: PARTITION_DATE=20170712/my-parquet-files-go-here, this will create more directories in your home folder. {PARTITION_YEAR=2017/PARTITION_MONTH=07/...} this will form a tree structure at the root of which will be the 'year' folder, month will be 1st child folder and 'date' will be 2nd child folder.

Comment: Why the question was down voted???

Comment: Don't know man. I upvoted the question, now it's 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since in both cases you are storing data with daily granularity, given the appropriate implementation at read time these two should be equivalent, but the former allows you to define better grained pruning based on your needs: you can easily get data for a whole year, a single month or a single day (or a combination of those) with well supported [glob patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)).

I'd encourage you to use the former solution to be more flexible, as for your current use case the efficiency doesn't change significantly.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly advise against having many, many folders in your s3 store. Why? Spark uses S3 connectors which mimic directory trees through multiple HTTP requests: the deeper and wider the tree, the more inefficient this becomes, not least because AWS S3 throttles HTTP requests

The year/month/day naming scheme works well with hive & spark, but if you go into too much depth (by day, by hour) then you may experience worse performance than if you didn't.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is quite simple... it depends on how you will query the data!

If you are querying purely on a range of days, then the second option is the easiest:

```
SELECT ...
FROM table
WHERE date BETWEEN ... AND ...
```

If you partition by month and day, you'd have to write a WHERE clause that uses both fields, which would be difficult if the desired 7-day range straddles two moths (eg 2018-05-27 to 2015-06-02):

```
SELECT ...
FROM table
WHERE (month = 5 and date BETWEEN 27 AND 31) OR
      (month = 6 and date BETWEEN 1 AND 2)
```

This is the best way to make the partitions work, but is not very efficient for coding.

**Thus, if you are using a WHERE on the `date`, then partition by `date`!**